# How to get selected option using ElementRef?

Tags: angular, viewchild, elementref

I have a table where i can add dynamic rows to the table using ADD button.

To construct this table i have taken form array.

Each row is having a select box with list of options

**scenario**

once the user selected a option from select box and when he click on ADD button to add new row next time the previously selection option should be disabled.

I am able to get selected option value form below code

```
  @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: ElementRef;
```

But it is giving me alway first row selected option only always.

Comment: not going into the point that you should probably thinking about doing it differently, but have you tried `@ViewChildren`?

Comment: @ViewChildren also giving same result but as a list.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `ElementRef` to achieve this as you will not be able to control your data in your `component.ts`, you can simply push an empty object as below,

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of array">
        <td>
            <select [(ngModel)]="row.gender">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female"> Female</option>
      </select>
        </td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="addNewItem()">Add New</button>
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Typescript code

```
array=[{
    gender:'male'
  }]

addNewItem(){
  const newItem={
     gender:''
  }
  this.array.push(newItem)
}
```

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axerec)

Note - This is a very basic example, comment on this so I can help you to build complex ones